# Java Job Interview Threads Programming Test. What answer do they want?

Tags: java, multithreading

Edit:
I added the implementation I used below and...

...I see what I did wrong: while the AtomicInteger balance object
is (I think) thread safe, two operations are involved, i.e. getting
the current balance, then updating it. So balance could change in
between getting it and updating it.

Still though, I'm still wondering what's the best solution for this and
what they were looking for.

(Also, as far as extensibility goes, e.g. the potential to transfer
balances, I intentionally did not address it. It seemed beyond the
scope of the assignment. My bad if it wasn't)

---

I just got my second negative response on a do-at-home programming test
involving threads given by a prospective employer.

I don't know if the solution I gave was necessarily wrong - it may just not
be the one they wanted. At this point though, I'm confused and have no
idea what that is.

This is basically the Java problem you're given:

```
public interface BalanceManagementSystem { //Edit: Changed name 
 /**
  * Deduct 'amountToWithdraw' of the given 'accountId' from account.
  * @param accountId The ID of the account to withdraw from
  * @param amountToWithdraw The quantity to withdraw
  * @return TODO: to be implemented
  */
 WithdrawalResult withdrawFromAccount(String accountId, int amountToWithdraw);

 /**
  * Add 'amountToDeposit' of the given accountId to inventory.
  * @param accountId The ID of the account to deposit to
  * @param amountToDeposit The quantity to deposit
  * @return TODO: to be implemented
  */
 DepositResult depositToAccount(String accountId, int amountToDeposit);
}
```

...so you have to implement the interface with thread-safe methods for
the two above. That I know.

No external dependencies beyond the standard JDK packages can be used.

The rest of the requirements were a little vague. I wound up, in the
absence of a database, using:

1. A HashMap as a data structure that contains (my own) Account
   objects.
2. An AtomicInteger to store the balance in an Account object, to
   enforce thread safety.

Apparently this was not the answer they wanted. I'm pretty sure the
thread safety issue is where things went wrong.

So, to an employer or manager who gives and evaluates a thread test
like this or an employee who's passed one, what solution is being
asked for?

---

Note

The HashMap used for storage uses accountId as the key.

AtomicInteger does not contain a subtractAndGet() so I subclassed it, creating AtomicIntegerPlus which does. subtractAndGet() is just a slight modification on the native addAndGet().

```
class Account {
    private String accountId;

    private AtomicIntegerPlus balance; //Thread-safe object subclassed from AtomicInteger

    Account(String acctId, String loc, AtomicIntegerPlus amt) {
        this.accountId = acctId;
        this.balance = amt;
    }

    public void addToBalance(int amt) {
        balance.addAndGet(amt);
    }

    public void subtractFromBalance(int amt) {
        balance.subtractAndGet(amt);
    }
}

class BMS implements BalanceManagementSystem {
    private HashMap<String, Account> hashMap;
    -
    -

    /**
    * Deduct 'amountToWithdraw' of the given 'accountId' from account.
    * @param accountId The ID of the account to withdraw from
    * @param amountToWithdraw The quantity to withdraw
    * @return withdrawalResult
    */
    public WithdrawalResult withdrawFromAccount(String accountId, int amountToWithdraw) {

        if (hashMap.containsKey(accountId)) {           
            Account tmpAccount = (Account)hashMap.get(accountId);           
            int balance = tmpAccount.getBalance();

            if (balance >= amountToWithdraw) {              
                tmpAccount.subtractFromBalance(amountToWithdraw);
                hashMap.put(tmpAccount.getAccountId(), tmpAccount); //Updatebalance with new amount

                withdrawalResult.setMessage("Withdrawn. You now have " + tmpAccount.getBalance() + " left");

            } else {
                withdrawalResult.setMessage("Don't have the balance for your request. Only " + balance + " left");
            }

        } else {
            withdrawalResult.setMessage("Sorry: account id " + accountId + " does not exist");
        }

        return withdrawalResult;
    }

    /**
    * Add 'amountToDeposit' of the given accountId to inventory.
    * @param accountId The ID of the account to deposit to
    * @param amountToDeposit The quantity to deposit
    * @return depositResult
    */
    public DepositResult depositToAccount(String accountId, int amountToDeposit) {      

        if (hashMap.containsKey(accountId)) {           
            Account tmpAccount = (Account)hashMap.get(accountId);

            tmpAccount.addToBalance(amountToDeposit);       
            hashMap.put(tmpAccount.getAccountId(), tmpAccount);// Update Balance with new amount

            depositResult.setMessage("Deposited. You now have " + tmpAccount.getBalance() + " left");

        } else {
            depositResult.setMessage("Sorry: account id " + accountId + " does not exist");
        }

        return depositResult;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your answer is too basic meaning you haven't really worked with threading a lot in your programs.

Comment: This is a bit too open-ended. Better if you show us your answer so we can critique it.

Comment: How did you ensure thread safety while accessing and updating the hash map?

Comment: @John Kugelman I populate the HashMap with Account objects. An Account object contains a member to hold the account balance that is defined as an AtomicInteger (which is thread safe on its own).

Comment: You haven't written whether you you took a lock on the hashmap or used a concurrent one. If not that might be an error (since new accounts need to created). The AtomicInteger won't buy you much in this scenario if you need to lock the hashmap anyway, because updating the balance is a fast operation compared and there's no benefit of doing it outside the hashmap lock.

Comment: But anyway, the reasons why they did not like the solution could be totally different: Maybe they would have liked another implementation of `WithdrawalResult` - e.g. which contains some errors if the balance is negative. Or they wanted to see the accout implemented with not just only a number but a complete transaction log, where only the aggregate of the log yields the total balance (EventSourcing style).

Comment: As I said in my answer, and even with the update you included in the question, you should read about java semaphores. That may not be the perfect solution for the problem, but it will show them that you have some knowledge about java concurrency and thread-safe methods

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution that you provided shows several weaknesses:

a) You seem to have not fully understood the difference between reference types (classes in Java) and value types. This is indicated by the following piece of code:

```
Account tmpAccount = (Account)hashMap.get(accountId);
// ...
tmpAccount.subtractFromBalance(amountToWithdraw);
hashMap.put(tmpAccount.getAccountId(), tmpAccount);
```

Here you are fetching an object of type Account by reference from the map and change it's state (with `substractFromBalance`). There is no need to put it back into the map - you have updated the reference which is still stored in the map - not a copy of it.

This error goes together with

b) No synchronization around the HashMap

If the accounts change during the lifecycle (which is quite normal for a banking system) then you would need synchronization for all accesses to the hashMap. You don't do anything for that. You might be able to argue that the accounts are fixed up from the start of the program and never change - which would allow you to elide the synchronization. However in your code example you prevent yourself from such an argumentation: By calling `hashMap.put(...)` you mutate the hashMap, which is non threadsafe operation.

c) You have a race condition in your program between checking the balance and updating it. If some other thread also withdraws from the account in between you can end up with a negative balance. If you go for atomics you would need a compareExchange loop here.

d) Possibly incorrect implementation of atomic add

I can only speculate about this since you didn't provide the source code of `AtomicIntegerPlus`. My first thought is: You don't need this, because the normal `AtomicInteger` already has everything you need. And your program does not require a `substractAndGet` either (you never use the return value). Then the question is how you have implemented it: If it's like  `AtomicInteger.addAndGet(-value); return AtomicInteger.get();` then it's wrong since it's not atomic anymore. And `AtomicInteger.addAndGet(-value);` would already have been sufficient anyway.

A simple correct solution would simply have used a lock around the HashMap and would not even have required atomics:

```
public WithdrawalResult withdrawFromAccount(String accountId, int amountToWithdraw) {
    WithdrawalResult withDrawalResult = new WithdrawalResult();

    synchronized(hashMap) {
        Account account = hashMap.get(accountId);    
        if (account != null) {                           
            int balance = account.getBalance();
            if (balance >= amountToWithdraw) {              
                account.setBalance(balance - amountToWithdraw);
                withdrawalResult.setMessage("Withdrawn. You now have " +   tmpAccount.getBalance() + " left");
            } else {
                withdrawalResult.setMessage("Don't have the balance for your request. Only " + balance + " left");
            }
        } else {
            withdrawalResult.setMessage("Sorry: account id " + accountId + " does not exist");
        }
    }

    return withdrawalResult;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Assume that you have 1000 on specific account. Two concurrent withdrawals for 900 are happening. Was your AtomicInteger based solution making sure that you won't end up with negative amount? It can be done (by compareAndSet in loop for example), but is probably slightly overcomplicated compared to synchronization.

In my experience, actual question (might be a followup to your implementation) is not about just implementing withdraw or deposit in thread-safe way, but to make a **transfer** between two accounts in thread safe way. You need to make sure that you won't overdraft an account in case of concurrent transactions and that you won't end up in deadlock if you use trivial synchronization scheme and end up with crossing transfers. AtomicInteger based solution makes it considerably harder to implement and reason about (I would still accept it, but you would need to be 100% sure about defending your CAS logic)

Comment: Iterface presented in question does not allow atomic transfer between two accounts, since methods presented are single-account only, while interaccount transfer requires locking both accounts at once. Overdrafting account is also likely left outside of scope of this task (at least question author does not mention it at all), and certain banking systems actually allow account to go into negative balance dependent on their business rules.

Comment: There will always be some limit - be it zero or -gazzilion, but not infinite. If it was not specified in interface, maybe their expectation was for candidate to ask about it, or at least chose the implementation which would trivially allow adding it, rather than require major change to achieve it. As for account transfer - indeed, this is why I suggest it as possible followup, to see how well your solution adapts to changing requirements. It depends on philosophy - I was on interviews where they would deduct points for solutions which forsee next steps, rather than religiously stick to YAGNI.

Answer (score 0):

> A HashMap as a data structure that contains (my own) Account objects.

You first problem is that `HashMap` is not a synchronized class and you do not seem to be protecting it from simultaneous access.  If 2 threads try to access the same `HashMap` at the same time, you can get data corruption, infinite loops, etc..

A quick solution would be to use a `ConcurrentHashMap` which will stop your program from crashing but doesn't fully handle the race conditions in your code.  What you need to worry about is if 2 threads are going to make the first operation on an account at the same time.  If you are always doing a `put(...)` operation then the 2nd thread will overwrite the first.  You need to use `ConcurrentHashMap`'s `putIfAbsent(...)` method.   Something like:

```
Account account = concurrentMap.get(accountId);
if (account == null) {
   account = new Account();
   Account oldAccount = concurrentMap.putIfAbsent(accountId, account);
   if (oldAccount != null) {
      // some other thread beat us to it
      account = oldAccount;
   }
}
```

Another problem that I see is that you are re-putting the `Account` into the map.   This should be done only once in the code above.  It should be in a `getAccount(accountId)` method shared by both of your methods.

> ...I see what I did wrong: while the AtomicInteger balance object is (I think) thread safe, two operations are involved, i.e. getting the current balance, then updating it. So balance could change in between getting it and updating it.

This is also a problem which takes some skill in solving.   Any of your update loops need to be something like the following pseudo-code:

```
while (true) {
   int balance = account.getBalance();
   // test balance and print error here
   int newBalance = balance + adjustment;
   if (account.adjustBalance(balance, newBalance)) {
      break;
   }
}
```

Then in your `Account` object you would do something like:

```
 public boolean adjustBalance(int oldBalance, int newBalance) {
    // this returns true if balance is still oldBalance and only then it updates it to new
    return balance.compareAndSet(oldBalance, newBalance);
 }
```

Whenever you are updating your balance, you need to get the value, change the value, and then try to store it back but this should *only* succeed if the balance has not be updated by another thread in the meantime.  This loop is a very typical pattern which is used in many different places in the JDK and elsewhere.

Lastly, I think it is overkill to extend `AtomicInteger` to add `subtractAndGet(...)`.  `AddAndGet(...)` with a negative number would be have been quite fine.